# How do I find all non-overlapping combinations

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a straight line of length N, the index position starts from 1 not 0.

Points are marked on this line using startIndex and endIndex pair.

Calculate the total number of non-intersecting pairs

**Example:**

starting = [1, 4, 6, 7] ending = [3, 5, 8, 10]

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
|----|              1 to 3
      |-|           4 to 5
         |----|         6 to 8
        |------|        7 to 10

We can select a pair if they are not overlapping.

Available pairs are:

1 -> (1,3)
2 -> (4,5)
3 -> (6, 8)
4 -> (7, 10)
The following combinations can be chosen:
• 1 and 2
• 1 and 3
• 1 and 4
• 2 and 3
• 2 and 4


So we have 5 possible nonoverlapping pairs

Result = 5
```

**Constrains:**

```
array values in range 1 to 10^9
length of starting and ending arrays is 1 to 10^5
```

My approach is to create a Tree Map with key as starting index and value as the list of ending index and corresponding position. But I am stuck when input is having duplicate entries for start or end timings.

I can use brute-force approach but that is not time efficient, so how to solve this?

**Sample test case with duplicates:**

```
Starting = 26, 49, 28, 10, 41, 83, 84, 1, 32, 20, 13, 74, 1, 3, 11, 5, 4, 74, 36, 14

Ending = 96, 78, 99, 59, 75, 99, 91, 73, 39, 96, 35, 81, 92, 39, 36, 33, 97, 95, 76, 73

Expected result : 52
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78202488/combination-of-non-overlapping-interval-pairs/78203661#78203661) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort starts and endings separately.
Walk through endings array.
For every ending find index `i` of the first start after it and add `(n-i)` to result (number of intervals after current ending)

Python code as  proof of concept (gives 52)

```
starting = [26, 49, 28, 10, 41, 83, 84, 1, 32, 20, 13, 74, 1, 3, 11, 5, 4, 74, 36, 14]
ending = [96, 78, 99, 59, 75, 99, 91, 73, 39, 96, 35, 81, 92, 39, 36, 33, 97, 95, 76, 73]
starting.sort()
ending.sort()
i = 0
n = len(starting)
res = 0
for x in ending:
    while (i < n) and (starting[i] <= x):
        i += 1
    res += (n-i)
print(res)
```

Comment: if we sort starting and ending separately, the positions will change right, so a pair with [start, end] will have different index positions

Comment: This fact does not influence on correctness. We don't need pairs themselves, just their count. Moreover, we cannot list these pairs because enumeration would require quadratic time.

Comment: I am still trying to understand how it works. Going through my example above `(1,3), (4,5), (6,8), (7,10)` if I select a start end combination `(1,3)`, I can pair with other items whose start position is greater than `3`. Same way for start-end pair `(4,5)` I need to find items whose starting point is more than `5` to make a combination. So If I sort start array and end array separately then how can I maintain this relationship

Comment: @learner When you're looking a pair to match, only its start position matters. Its end position will never be less than its start position.

Comment: @learner  Your task is "**Calculate** the total number of non-intersecting pairs" - so you can forget relationship between starts and endings.  It is possible to get pairs  - but this is not required.